# How do you build LGPL version of ffmpeg with libmp3lame?

Tags: compilation, ffmpeg, cross-compiling

I have a task to convert mp3 file + some picture into mp4 video. To do that I'm using ffmpeg library + libmp3lame, but I have to use LGPL version. So I'm trying to build it with appropriate flags, since I can't find it in the internet.

And I also need a win64 version, but I have to build it on Ubuntu VM (vagrant).

Here is my script (a part from the vagrantfile):

```
 sudo apt-get install -y mingw-w64
 sudo apt-get install -y git     

 wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/lame/lame/3.99/lame-3.99.5.tar.gz
 tar xzvf lame-3.99.5.tar.gz
 cd lame-3.99.5
 ./configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --prefix="/vagrant/ffmpeg_build" --disable-shared --enable-static
 make
 make install

 cd /vagrant

 git clone https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg.git              
 cd FFmpeg/  
 ./configure --prefix="/vagrant/ffmpeg_build" --arch=x86_64 --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --target-os=mingw32 --enable-static --disable-shared --disable-debug --disable-yasm --disable-w32threads --disable-network --extra-libs=-static --extra-cflags="-I/vagrant/ffmpeg_build/include" --extra-ldflags="-L/vagrant/ffmpeg_build/lib"        
 make
```

Unfortunately in the very end of the build process I get

```
==> default: CC ffmpeg_opt.o
==> default: CC ffmpeg_filter.o
==> default: CC ffmpeg_dxva2.o
==> default: LD ffmpeg_g.exe
==> default: CP ffmpeg.exe
==> default: STRIP      ffmpeg.exe
==> default: x86_64-w64-mingw32-strip
==> default: :stgaDQCc
==> default: : Protocol error
==> default: make:
==> default: *** [ffmpeg.exe] Error 1
```

What am I missing with my configuration? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like it can't find x86_64-w64-mingw32-strip or the invocation doesn't accept the options given to it. Run "make V=1" to see the exact invocation and see how to mold it so it works.

Comment: @Ronald S. Bultje: I have tried that, it looks like x86_64-w64-mingw32-strip does exist, the only error I get is a "Protocol error".
If I run separately this command I get "Copy from 'ffmpeg.exe'  [pei-x86-64] to 'st4MaMIc' [pei-x86-64]" and a  "Protocol error"

Comment: So figure out why - is your hard disk full?

Comment: No, it is not full, that's for sure :)

Comment: Is the location you're building on shared? (https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/8463)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're building in a VM, so the location you're building on may be a shared space between VM and host, which can result in "Protocol error" when running strip (see e.g. [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/8463)). Try unsharing the build folder or building in another location that is not shared.